# Google Speech-to-Text API 5 Minute Limit

Tags: audio, timeout, speech-to-text

Google Speech-to-Text API has a limit of 5 minutes for audio. Is there a way to circumvent this limit? If not, what alternatives exist to service longer audio files? Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that even with the Google Speech-to-Text streaming API the 5 minute limit is still in place (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas). So one would have to use the endless streaming (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endless-streaming-tutorial). Has anyone used endless streaming with Twilio?

Comment: Brian, appreciate the links you provided but they don't address the issue directly. Plus they are from 2017 and a lot has changed since then.